# Why is the month of Aprill masculine?

Tags: poetry, the-canterbury-tales, geoffrey-chaucer

In the first line of the General Prologue of *The Canterbury Tales*, the month of April is given a masculine pronoun:

> Whan that Aprill, with his shoures soote

Why is this?

Answer (score 20):

There have been a couple of different explanations given for this, but the upshot seems to be that **there's nothing particularly significant about the masculinity of April** - it was more a product of the way language was used at the time than any kind of symbolic statement about masculinity.

In his [*Notes to the Canterbury Tales* (2014)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AQRXCAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s), Prof Walter Skeat says that the masculinity of Aprille is derived from that of the Latin [*Aprilis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aprilis#Proper_noun). Latin was of course much more widely used, especially in literature, in Chaucer's day.

However, in his notes published [here](https://tigerweb.towson.edu/duncan/chaucer/notes-gpopening.html) and based on those of [Alfred Pollard](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dfjV8a75qV4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_slider_thumb&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=&f=false), Prof Edwin Duncan cites Skeat and then points out that:

> as *his* in Chaucer's time was the neuter, as well as the masculine, genitive, there is no evidence that Chaucer here personified either the month or the wind as a masculine.

The reason why "his" was used as a neuter pronoun is that **the word "its" didn't exist yet**. According to [Etymology Online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/its), the neuter possessive pronoun "its" dates back to around the 16th century, well after Chaucer's time. (Thanks to @GarethRees for pointing this out to me.)

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly a reference to astrology.  In western astrology, April is regarded as a masculine month.

April is the month of Aries, The Ram, a masculine sign.  It is ruled by Mars, a masculine planet.

As astrology was more highly regarded in Chaucer's time than today, he could well be making a reference to April's astrological masculinity.

However, to be sure of this as an explanation, a reference to a feminine month using feminine pronoun is needed.  I can't immediately think of such a reference.

Comment: "April is regarded as a masculine month." citation?